# How to implement Codeigniter syntaxed single where and orderby clause to multiple "get" queries?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a 2 `get` queries which is merged at the end using `array_merge()`, but before that my `where` and `order_by` clause gets implemented on first executing `get` query only as per OOPS concept. But I want this `where` and `order_by` clause to be implemented on both the queries, without writing a separate `where` and `order_by` clause for second executing query. My Code is below:

```
$this->db->where('lower(status) <>', 'completed');
$this->db->order_by('calldate','asc');

$q1 = $this->db->get('records'); //where and orderby applies to this query only
$q2 = $this->db->get('other_records'); //where and orderby does not apply to this
$data1 = $q1->result_array();
$data2 = $q2->result_array();
$data = array_merge($data1, $data2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        $this->db->where('lower(status) <>', 'completed');
        $this->db->order_by('calldate','asc');

        $q = $this->db->get('records'); //where and orderby applies to this query only
        $data1 = $q->result_array();
        $q = $this->db->get('other_records'); //where and orderby does not apply to this

        $data2 = $q->result_array();
        $data = array_merge($data1, $data2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write raw SQL with UNION. for example

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE lower(status)<>'completed' ORDER BY calldate ASC
UNION
SELECT * FROM other_records WHERE lower(status)<>'completed' ORDER BY calldate ASC
```

Then you can avoid sending 2 separate queries and merging array. It reduces network round-trip to send queries and CPU resource needed to merge array.

Comment: Agreed with that, But had to use CI standards.. and CI does not have Union specific syntax.. I will put the reasoning my retrospections...